# Add value in the last of each row in python

Tags: python

i am new in python. i try to add the integer in the end of each row and save that values in new file. here is current code.

```
    file = open("Task1.txt","r")
    f1 = open("out.txt", "w+")

    for line in file:
      if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
         for l in line.split():
               a = l[0]
               b = l[-1]
               l1= a + b
               s = sum(int(num) for num in l1) 
              for line1 in line:
                 f1.write(line1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include `Task1.txt`  or hardcode it in assuming it's being read OK. Thanks.

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables - it can help to see what code is doing.

Comment: you canlcuate some value but never write it . And I don't understand why do you use `for line1 in line: f1.write(line1)` which probably write line char-by-char  - you can write all line directly `f1.write(line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above, you need to first ensure that `l[0]` and `l[1]` are not strings as the `l1 = a + b` statement will just concatenate them.

If these are expected to be numbers, you can use:
`a, b = int(l[0]), int(l[1])`
or better to use:
`s = int(l[0]) + int(l[1])`

Currently, `s = sum(int(num) for num in l1)` will add up the digits in `l1` and will fail if one of the characters is a letter.

**For instance:** 
If `a = '12'` and `b = '34'`, `l1` will equal **1234**, and `s` will equal **10**.
If `a = '12'` and `b = '34a'`, `l1` will equal **1234a**, and `sum(int(num) for num in l1)` will **fail** as you are trying to make the last character `a` into an integer.